# Hide a post but make it accessible via a link Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to hide certain posts from displaying on the site using custom code. I CANNOT USE A PLUGIN!

I would like to do something like IF the page is named the-hidden-page do not display it anywhere on the site BUT someone can access it using a URL... For example, http://thedomain/the-hidden-page.

I haven't been successful finding sample code except for this -

```
<?php if (is_front_page() && !is_paged()
) $posts = query_posts($query_string . '&cat=-33,-66'); ?>
```

This code is using category names rather than page names.  Also if I used the code above I'm not sure where to add it to.  I tried function.php but that didn't work.

Can someone provide an example of how the code could be written to hide post with a certain name?

Also tell me in what file I should add your code to?

Comment: `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == 'http://thedomain/the-hidden-page'){do your stuff what you want in this case.}` add it on your `the-hidden-page.php`

Comment: Why is it confusing?

Comment: @Anat You would have to include that code on every page of your website. Additionally to avoid duplicate names, I would use `if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "the-hidden-page"){do your stuff what you want in this case.}`

Comment: Not in every page in `header.php` if it is included everywhere

Comment: @Anant The point of me using strpos() was to allow the blocking of multiple pages without them all being the exact same name. Additionally the chance of a page incidentally including `the-hidden-page` in the title is very slim.

Comment: Hidden page or hidden posts? Thats the default behavior of pages, not displayed anywhere unless you add it to the menu or to pages but still accessible by directly entering the URL.